# Pushing contents of struct type onto the stack in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, fasm

Lets say I have declared a struct like so:

```
struct VEC
    x   dd  ?
    y   dd  ?
ends
```

Then I declare some data as struct:

```
section '.data' data readable writeable
vec1            VEC     5,4
vec2            VEC     3,2
```

Now, I wish to push the contents of memory locations vec1 and vec2 to the stack. I do something like this:

```
push    sizeof.VEC [vec1]           
push    sizeof.VEC [vec2]
```

This doesn't compile. The error returned is:

`error: operand size not specified.`

I want to know if there is any way to put the contents of this struct type onto the stack. Or is this illegal in x86 in the first place?

I am compiling this on Windows 10 using flat assembler version 1.71.49

In general, my question is about how to get the assembler to encode a push [mem] with the right operand-size

Comment: `sizeof.VEC` is a numeric expression.  Does `8 [vec1]` mean `[vec1+8]` in FASM?  If so, that's what you'd get (if you used it in a context where the operand-size was implied by something else, or with `qword` or `qword ptr`.  Anyway, this is just a question of how to get your assembler to encode a `push [mem]` with the right operand-size.  (16bit and 64bit pushes are encodable in 64bit mode, but not 32bit pushes.  `REX.W=0 push something` faults as an illegal instruction, contrary to Intel's insn ref manual claiming that the operand-size may be overridden with `66H` or `REX.W`)

Comment: In general, like you pointed out my question is about how to get the assembler to encode a push [mem] with the right operand-size

Comment: That was in response to *Or is this illegal in x86 in the first place?*.  That's trivial: if your struct is 16 or 64b, they yes.  Otherwise no!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a question of how to get your assembler to encode a `push [mem]` with the right operand-size.  16bit and 64bit `push`es are encodable in 64bit mode, but not 32bit `push`es.  `REX.W=0 push something` faults as an illegal instruction, contrary to Intel's insn ref manual claiming that the operand-size may be overridden with 66H or REX.W:

> Operand size. The D flag in the current code-segment descriptor determines the default operand size; it may
>   be overridden by instruction prefixes (66H or REX.W).
>   The operand size (16, 32, or 64 bits) determines the amount by which the stack pointer is decremented (2, 4
>   or 8).

Note that this is documenting 32 and 64bit mode.  32bit pushes are of course available in 32bit mode.  ([x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki for links to the manual)

---

Since there are lots of struct sizes that aren't pushable with a single instruction, it's unlikely that there's any syntax for choosing a word, dword or qword operand-size based on the struct size.  You might use macros to do it yourself, though, if you really wanted.

`push`ing large structs is not how normal calling conventions work, so that's another reason there isn't syntactic sugar for it.  Normally objects too large to fit in a register are passed by reference.  Smaller objects can be passed by value.  So **you can't just parameterize the operand-size of the `push` to make flexible code**; you'd need to use a macro to emit a different instruction to pass by value vs. pass by reference, depending on the size of the struct.

Since your struct is 64bit, you can only push a whole struct with a single instruction in 64bit mode:

```
push qword [vec1]
push qword [vec2]
```

(Or `qword ptr`, if FASM uses MASM syntax instead of NASM).